# Jquery radio button starts endless loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to get an answer from the php file if I click on one of the radio buttons, but if I use the radio button, the alert appers in an endless loop. Why? And how do I get the alert only once?

I try it with only a „normal“ button, then it works:
If I click on the button, the ajax responds the values in the alert once.

Thank you

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <br>
      <br>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="go">Go</button>
      <div class="row">
        
        <div class="btn-group"  id="auswahl" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn-outline-primary active">
            <input type="radio"  name="aktionswahl" value="alles" checked autocomplete="off"> Alles
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
            <input type="radio"  name="aktionswahl" value="blue" autocomplete="off"> blue
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
            <input type="radio"  name="aktionswahl" value="red" autocomplete="off"> red
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--Container-->

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
     crossorigin="anonymous">></script>

    <script>


      $(function() {
        $("input[name=aktionswahl]").focus(function () {
          //var auswahl = this.value;
          var sqlwhere = "where aktion=4 and Datum >= '2017-12-05' and Datum < '2017-12-07'";
          ask(sqlwhere);
        });
      });
      
      $(function() {
        $("#go").click(function () {
          var sqlwhere = "where aktion=4 and Datum >= '2017-12-05' and Datum < '2017-12-07'";

          ask(sqlwhere);

        });
      });
      
      function ask(sqlwhere) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'read_sql.php',
            data: { sqlwhere:sqlwhere }
            }).done(function(data) { alert(data); });
            return false;
      }
    
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `alert` appears, the radio button will lose focus. As you close the `alert`, the focus will return which triggers the `alert` which causes the radio button to lose focus but when you close that `alert` ...

Use `console.log` instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this, your code is right just need one change...
write return false; immediately after alert.
means...function(data) { alert(data); return false; }